# Identity Framework Use Principal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

In the [tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-identity-tutorial/)
there's this paragraph:

> When the user logs in for the first time, this middleware serializes a
>   **user principal** into an encrypted cookie and sends it to the Browser.
>   On subsequent requests, it reads the cookie, validates the cookie,
>   recreates the **user principal**, and assigns it to the HttpContext.User
>   property. This you can then access in your controller Property using
>   Request.User

What is **User Principal**?

Comment: That represents the current user in a request .

Comment: @NanYu that's not quite true.  The Identity of a Principal can be null, so it's not quite a User and is better described as it is an *encapsulation of a security context*.

Answer (score 4):

**Principal** represents the security context under which request is running. In ASP.NET Core the user principal can be accessed by accessing the property `HttpContext.User` from a controller. If you need to access it somewhere else in your application but still in the context of a web request you can use `IHttpContextAccessor` to get an access to `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the *Principle* Microsoft refers to is an implementation of the [IPrincipal Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=netframework-4.8) (.Net and/or Core).

There are a number of types that derive from an `IPrincipal` including:

[ClaimsPrincipal Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

[ClientRolePrincipal Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.clientservices.clientroleprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

[GenericPrincipal Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.genericprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

[WindowsPrincipal Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

You can also create your own Principal class and customize it however you want.

[Principal Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects#principal-objects)

> The principal object represents the security context under which code is running. Applications that implement role-based security grant rights based on the role associated with a principal object. Similar to identity objects, the .NET Framework provides a GenericPrincipal object and a WindowsPrincipal object. You can also define your own custom principal classes.

One of the required properties of a Principal is the Identity:

[Identity Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects#identity-objects)

> The identity object encapsulates information about the user or entity being validated. At their most basic level, identity objects contain a name and an authentication type. The name can either be a user's name or the name of a Windows account, while the authentication type can be either a supported logon protocol, such as Kerberos V5, or a custom value. The .NET Framework defines a GenericIdentity object that can be used for most custom logon scenarios and a more specialized WindowsIdentity object that can be used when you want your application to rely on Windows authentication. Additionally, you can define your own identity class that encapsulates custom user information.

Additional Reading:  [Key Security Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/key-security-concepts)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cookie middleware to implement cookie authentication,to create a cookie holding user information, construct a `ClaimsPrincipal`. The user information is serialized and stored in the cookie.

The `User Principle` is the `ClaimsPrinciple`,

```
public class MyCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{


    public override async Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal  userPrincipal = context.Principal;

    }
}
```

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-an-authentication-cookie